# Is there a way to find out how many items total (games, software, videos) are available in Steam Discovery Queue?

Tags: steam

I know there are regional restrictions that prevent certain items from appearing in restricted countries, but in general, how to calculate the number of games which you could go through if you browse through all the items in the Discovery Queue?

Answer (score 1):

The only people that know what's going to be in the discovery queue, are the programmers who designed it. But... We can figure out how many games, apps, and videos there are in general.

Simply go this link: https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Released_DESC&category1=998

You'll notice that no tags are checked and selected type is: Games

At the bottom left it shows (currently) showing 1 - 25 of **29799**

Software (currently): showing 1 - 25 of **771**

Videos (currently): showing 1 - 25 of **367**

Total Items on steam: **53404**

Comment: In the Discovery Queue, these numbers are also slimmed down based on personal preferences. (And regional limitations, indeed: I see a total of 29521 games.)